# JQuery in VirtualDOM Buffer Rows

Tags: tabulator

I have a column of checkboxes in my table that I want to have checked with parity in row.isSelected().

When using the VirtualDOM the rows in the buffer don't get checked/unchecked as part of a table.getRows() loop to un-check the box.  The rows DO get unselected from the table POV via row.deselect().

The checkbox is added with a mutator to the first column:

```
  checkboxMutator = function (value, data) {
        return '<input type="checkbox" class="rowCheckBox" name="' + value + '">';
}
```

The select all logic:

```
$("#select-all").click(function () {
    var rows = table.getRows(true);
    rows.forEach(function(row){
            row.select();
            $("input[name='" + row.getData().index + "']:checkbox").prop('checked', true);
    });
});
```

The rows that don't exist in the DOM at all yet can be checked by adding some logic into rowFormatter to check them on render the first time.

It might not be possible to fix, but I thought it was worth asking about.

Answer (score 1):

Because Tabulator uses a vitrual DOM only the rows that are visible actually exists, rows are created and destroyed as you scroll.

Because of this it is not safe to try and manipulate any DOM elements inside the table from outside.

In your case you should be using a [Custom Formatter](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.1/format#format-custom) that uses the ***isSelected*** function on the row component to determine if the checkbox should be selected when it is created.

```
//custom formatter
function checkboxFormatter(cell, formatterParams, onRendered){

    //create input element
    var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");


    //set checked state
    input.checked = cell.getRow().isSelected();

    return input;
}

//assign formatter in column definition
{title:"selected?", formatter:checkboxFormatter}
```

You should then be using the ***rowSelectionChanged*** option to redraw the row after selection has changed, which will then cause the formatter to run and update the checkbox.

```
rowSelectionChanged:function(data, rows){
    //rows - array of row components for the selected rows in order of selection
    //data - array of data objects for the selected rows in order of selection

    //reformat all rows that have changed
    rows.forEach(function(row){
        row.reformat();
    })
}
```

You can then select all rows in the table by calling the ***selectRow*** function on the table.

```
table.selectRow();
```